# Can an ebook on essays sell good on amazon/kindle?

Tags: kindle

I am a newbie writer, and I am thinking of writing an ebook on collection of essays, and i need to know whether such genre sell good on amazon/kindle?

Comment: You would also need to improve your writing skills. English language stackexchange could be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If you plan to write, forget about making money. The return per hour, is dismal. If you want to write, write for it's own sake. If you want to earn money,do not write.